# Mesh disappears partly while sculpting

Tags: mesh, sculpting

while sculpting a terrain model most of the time cannot see what I am sculpting as the mesh "disappears" on the location I am sculpting and somewhat around it but not the complete terrain mesh. Any suggestions what the cause of this is? I am using Blender 2.78a.
Here's a video of what I am seeing:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oQ97_FNFhlQ&feature=youtu.be
Thanks

Comment: That link looks very sketchy, could you please upload to a trusted long-term video hosting site like YouTube?

Comment: @veryRandomMe I believe it's just it's OneDrives short link.

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem by correcting the clip end distance (under View) in the 3d viewport. It had an erroneous value of 5000km. After changing this to 10 km the mesh did not disappear anymore while sculpting.

Comment: @Niuskir thanks !! This issue was driving me crazy.

Comment: Look if you have an unused modifier on the object, I had the same problem and it solved it.